# OpenRefine - remove first dot in every word

Tags: latitude-longitude, openrefine

I am using OpenRefine and have values like:

```
33.469.444  or 3.333.444
```

which I want to convert to:

```
33469.444 or 3333.444
```

So I want to remove the first dot (".") in every word.

Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Jython instead of GREL... you can take advantage of a cool function called

`replace(new,old,[max occurances])` like so:

```
return value.replace(".","",1)
```

If you need to remove the first 4 period characters then:

```
return value.replace(".","",4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `split()` function to select the first. You can do something like this:
`value.split(".")[0] + value.split(".")[1] + "." + value.split(".")[2]`

This will split the value on into an array based on the `.`

- `value.split(".")[0]` select the first element in the array
- `+ value.split(".")[1]`select the second element and add it to the first (and remove the dot)
- `+ "." +` add the dot needed in the rest of the string
- `value.split(".")[2]` select the third element in the array